# Django: Extremely slow page loading using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

For testing purposes, I tried to host my current Django project on my Raspberry Pi (Model B) using apache and mod_wsgi. After some struggling I managed to get it to work. Unfortunately, page loading is extremely slow (from 30 seconds up to a few minutes, even on the stock admin site) although it worked quite well on the Django development server.

Here is the corresponding extract of my `etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, as I'm sure this is just a problem with my configuration (I used [the official Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#basic-configuration)):

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/Vplan/Vertretungsplan/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/Vplan

<Directory /var/Vplan/Vertretungsplan>
<Files wsgi.py>
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Does/Did anybody experience similar problems or knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you see if Apache is launching too many worker processes / using too much memory?

Comment: It seems like apache neither uses too much memory nor launches too many processes (it's only one, at least from what I can tell using `htop`). CPU usage raises to 100% during page load.

Comment: Just to ensure you do not run up against memory issues later, ensure you are not using embedded mode of mod_wsgi, don't use Apache prefork MPM and ensure you are using a recent mod_wsgi version. Some details on why you do not want to use embedded mode described in http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip! In the meantime, I switched from sqlite3 to MySQL - but still no significant improvements...

Comment: Same problem here - Django 1.8, Python 2.7.6. Anyone managed to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [mod_wsgi daemon mode.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-mod-wsgi-daemon-mode)

Comment: Please give some information explaining why this will help. If the page you linked has that information, it should be in your answer too so that stackoverflow itself has a complete answer.

Comment: The better link is the one I already gave in comment on question. http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html Copying information from an authoritative source should be discouraged, not encouraged. Yes explain why the information in the outside link should be read, but don't go copying the contents.